# Any way to use common variable for all tab in tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

i am creating 4 tab in tabbarcontroller,i want use common variable like name in all tabs how to do that

Thanks

Comment: Please post your codes so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: why do you need to know the names of your tabs? can't you just assign them in your NIB/XIB file?

Comment: i do it by using self.navigationController.navigationBar.accessibilityValue

Answer (score 2):

By declaring object in AppDelegate would be most easiest way to access object in all four tab. Do something like..

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *strName;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//Set Value
appDelegate.strName = @"Some value";
//Get Value
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.strName);
```

Comment: thank you but i don't want to create a variable